# How to fetch data before route change?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router

I'm trying to have the following user flow when a user click on a link:

- The user clicks on a link
- A progress bar appears at the top of the page
- The JS launches a network request to fetch some data from the server
- When done, the progress bar finishes, and the page is switch

Note that I don't want to have any spinner or skeleton page. When the user clicks on the link, the page should not change at all (apart from the progress bar appearing) until the data has been fetched from the server, similar to how GitHub works.

I've searched a lot about this on the last few days, and it seems that it's not possible to do this:

- Apparently, there used to be a `onEnter` hook that made it possible to achieve my described flow, but it was removed because, according to the devs, React lifecycle hooks were enough to achieve this.
- React lifecycle hooks are not enough because if I use them to trigger the network request, the page will be blank between the click on the link and the response of the network request.
- I could make a wrapper on top of the Link component so that when the user clicks on it, the network request is triggered and only after it's finished, `router.navigate` would be called. It seems nice at first, but it doesn't solve the issue of the initial visit to a page, where a Link button has not been called at all.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I created a workaround for such behaviour: [react-router-loading](https://github.com/victortrusov/react-router-loading). It allows you to fetch data before switching the page.

You only need to replace `Switch` / `Routes` and `Route` with ones from the package, mark some (or all) routes with the `loading` prop and tell the router when to switch pages using the context in components:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-loading";

<Routes> // or <Switch> for React Router 5
    <Route path="/page1" element={<MyPage1 />} loading />
    <Route path="/page2" element={<MyPage2 />} loading />
    ...
</Routes>
```

```
// MyPage1.jsx

import { useLoadingContext } from "react-router-loading";
const loadingContext = useLoadingContext();

const loading = async () => {
    // fetching data

    // call method to indicate that fetching is done and we are ready to switch pages
    loadingContext.done();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

write a onClick function for  your component

then function like this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history=useHistory();
const [loading,setLaoding]=React.useState(false);
const myfunction=async()=>{
setLoading(true);
 const res= await fetch("your link here");
 const data=res.json();
if(res.status===200)
{
console.log(succusfully fetch data)
setLoading(false);
 history.push("/your_destination");
}
else{
setLoading(false);
console.log("error in fetch data")
}
}
```

write link like this

```
{loading?<Spin/> :
    <p onClick={myfunction}>link</p>}
```